# show child div11 within the same parent div as another child tag p

Tags: jquery, hide, parent, show

I want to hide p by clicking on the (p) tag within the parent div(1 or 2 or 3) the p will disappear and the div div(11 or 12 or 13) p will appear in acordance with the p that disappeared in that division.

How do I do that without using ID names?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();

    //What do I need to put here?? to show the <p> in the <div id="11 or 12 or 13"> according to the <p> that is clicked

    });

});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class = "" id="1">
  <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>  // BY CLICKING THIS P HIDE IT THEN
  <div id="11" style="display:none;">
    <p>You have clicked me<p>                   // THEN SHOW THIS P
  </div>
</div> 
<span> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH </span>

<div id="2">
 <p>Click me away!</p>
 <div id="22" style="display:none;">
   <p>You have clicked me too!<p>
 </div>
</div>
<span> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH </span>

<div id="3">
 <p>Click me too!</p>
 <div id="33" style="display:none;">
   <p>You have clicked me three!<p>
 </div>
</div>
<span> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH </span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(this).next().show()` should be enough with given html

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this, see [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) or [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) in jquery doc.

```
$("div p").click(function(){
            $(this).hide().next().show();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Wolff. that did the job :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the div, next to the p show you can use $(this).next().show();

http://api.jquery.com/next/